# How get Child Objects of a Object In C#?

Tags: c#, .net, object

In VB.net , this code is ok:

```
Dim oPS as Object= CreateObject("Photoshop.Application.10")
Dim oDocument as Object= oPS.ActiveDocument
```

But in C#, this code occur error:

```
Object oPS = COMCreateObject("Photoshop.Application.10");
Object oDocument = oPS.ActiveDocument;
```

Error when build

```
Error   2   'object' does not contain a definition for 'ActiveDocument' and no extension method 'ActiveDocument' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How get Child Objects of a Object In C#(the same vb.net)?

Comment: Ummm... if you are expecting to access specific properties, why are you defining the variable as Object anyway? Surely you must know the real type if you know its properties.

Comment: Because i using multi version. so can't add dll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `dynamic` keyword instead of `object` :

```
dynamic oPS = COMCreateObject("Photoshop.Application.10");
dynamic oDocument = oPS.ActiveDocument;
```

MSDN reference here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

In .net 4 or later you should use `dynamic` for this purpose. This should be like:

```
var _type= Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Photoshop.Application.10");
dynamic inst= Activator.CreateInstance(_type);
inst.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic keyword for your problem.